# NSLayoutConstraint added programmatically but views are disappearing on push back

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm using Xcode 9 and iOS 11.
I want to add dynamically a banner in a view, resizing the least view to make enough space for the upcoming banner view...

I wrote up the following code that just works fine, very well, as it's supposed to be.

Once the banner is shown, the app workflow goes ahead, so the user might tap somewhere and a new UIViewController is pushed onto the navigation stack. When the user go back the previous view, where the banner is placed), all the view are disappeared... there's no more tableview nor bannerView, just an empty view!

I cannot figure why. Ideas?
I have no autolayout errors in console...

addBannerViewToView is called in viewDidload()

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(bannerView)

    var tableView: UIView?
    var ttconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    for constraint in view.constraints {
        if constraint.firstAnchor == bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor {
            tableView = constraint.secondItem as? UIView
            ttconstraint = constraint
        }
    }

    debugPrint(ttconstraint!)
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([ttconstraint!])

    print("LAST VIEW: \(tableView)")
    tableView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bannerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
            bannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bannerView.frame.height),

            tableView!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            tableView!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            tableView!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            tableView!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            ])
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
```

Comment: that initialization of the `tableView` and `ttConstraint` look really suspicious.. if you are using storyboards, why not `@IBOutlet`? plus that autolayout code is another thing - why not storyboards, but deactivating `ttConstraint` which I guess is done through storyboards and then rebuilding constraints?

Comment: tableView and ttconstraint are not initialized through the code, but they are found programmatically looping for constraints... tableview is just a reference to the bottom view in the hierarchy because I look for a view that has a constraint with the bottomLayoutGuide...
the first time the view is shown, everything is ok, there is no problem in using that vars (tableview and ttconstraint)